# PHP: Radio button creation?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp-3.0

I'm making a search form with [cakephp 3](http://cakephp.org/) and I have to use radio buttons.

I don't know how to make them with php. This is what I have so far:

```css
input[type=radio] + label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -2px 8px 0 0;    
  height: 23px;  
  width: 23px;  
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  
  content: "";  
  transition: box-shadow .01s .39s ease-in-out, background .4s ease-in-out;

}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  border: solid #F44336;
  background-color: #F44336;  
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="1">
              <label for="radio1">Product Shots</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="3">
              <label for="radio3">Video</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"> 
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="2">
              <label for="radio2">Printing Materials</label>
          </div>
```

The radio button beside the label doesn't appear:

```
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"> 
        <?= $this->Form->input('multimedia_type_id', ['type' => 'radio', 
                                                      'name' => 'radio',
                                                      'label' => false,
                                                      'options' => $multimediaTypes
                                                     ]); ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```css
input[type=radio] + label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -2px 8px 0 0;    
  height: 23px;  
  width: 23px;  
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  
  content: "";  
  transition: box-shadow .01s .39s ease-in-out, background .4s ease-in-out;

}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  border: solid #F44336;
  background-color: #F44336;  
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <input type="radio" id="1" name="multimedia_type_id" value="1"/>
              <label for="1">Product Shots</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <input type="radio" id="2" name="multimedia_type_id" value="2"/>
              <label for="2">Video</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"> 
              <input type="radio" id="3" name="multimedia_type_id" value="3"/>
              <label for="3">Printing Materials</label>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR CREATING RADIO BUTTONS IN CAKEPHP3**,

The syntax is:

```
Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::radio(string $fieldName, array $options, array $attributes)
```

- `value` - Indicates the value when this radio button is checked.
- `label` - boolean to indicate whether or not labels for widgets
  should be displayed.
- `hiddenField` - boolean to indicate if you want the results of `radio()` to include a hidden input with a value of ‘’. This is useful for creating radio sets that are non-continuous.
- `disabled` - Set to true or disabled to disable all the radio buttons.
- `empty` - Set to true to create an input with the value ‘’ as the first option. When true the radio label will be ‘`empty`’. Set this option to a string to control the label value.

Generally $options is a simple key => value pair. However, if you need to put custom attributes on your radio buttons you can use an expanded format:

```
echo $this->Form->radio(
    'favorite_color',
    [
        ['value' => 'r', 'text' => 'Red', 'style' => 'color:red;'],
        ['value' => 'u', 'text' => 'Blue', 'style' => 'color:blue;'],
        ['value' => 'g', 'text' => 'Green', 'style' => 'color:green;'],
    ]
);

// Will output
<input type="hidden" name="favorite_color" value="">
<label for="favorite-color-r">
    <input type="radio" name="favorite_color" value="r" style="color:red;" id="favorite-color-r">
    Red
</label>
<label for="favorite-color-u">
    <input type="radio" name="favorite_color" value="u" style="color:blue;" id="favorite-color-u">
    Blue
</label>
<label for="favorite-color-g">
    <input type="radio" name="favorite_color" value="g" style="color:green;" id="favorite-color-g">
    Green
</label>
```

For more details: check the [CakePHP3 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs).

Comment: thanks, now the search works, but the style don't load